# apache cxf simple REST api returns always 404

Tags: java, rest, cxf, apache-tomee

I have a test task - small REST api in apache CXF, which should take stock exchange rates from remote resources. I run this as a maven project (.war) and deploy through TomEE. I'm a newbie in this theme, that's why I can't figure out, why am I always receiving a 404 error.

that's my service:

```
@Path("stock")
public class StockService {
    private Stock stock = new Stock();
    
    @GET
    @Path("currencies")
    @Produces("text/json")
    public String getAllCurrencies() {
        return stock.getAllCurrenciesJson();
    }
    
    @GET
    @Path("{currency}/{date}")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getRateByDate(@PathParam("currency") String currency, 
            @PathParam("date") String date) {
        return stock.findRateByDate(Currency.findByShortcut(currency), date);
    }
    
    @GET
    @Path("{date}")
    @Produces("text/json")
    public String getAllRates(@PathParam("date") String date) {
        return stock.findAllRatesByDate(date);
    }
    
    @GET
    @Path("convert/{currency}/{date}")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getConversionByDate(@PathParam("currency") String currency,
            @PathParam("date") String date, Double amount) {
        return stock.convert(Currency.findByShortcut(currency), amount, date);
    }
}
```

I hide the model, because the problem is surely with the deployment. Then I have several pre-created classes, like:

```
@ApplicationPath("service")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        //I add this line
        classes.add(StockService.class);
        return classes;
    }

}
```

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class MyStartupBean {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyStartupBean.class);

    private final ServiceRegistryService serviceRegistryService;

    protected MyStartupBean() {
        this.serviceRegistryService = null;
    }

    @Inject
    public MyStartupBean(ServiceRegistryService serviceRegistryService) {
        this.serviceRegistryService = serviceRegistryService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        logger.info("Starting service");
        serviceRegistryService.registerService();
        logger.info("Started service");
    }
}
```

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceRegistryService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceRegistryService.class);
    public void registerService() {
        serviceRegistration = ServiceRegistry
                 .createRegistration("this.service.id:v1", "/service/")
                 .build();
        ServiceRegistry.submitRegistration(serviceRegistration);
        logger.info("Service registered as {}", serviceRegistration);
    }
}
```

My `web.xml` is empty (means no `servlet` or so tags are specified) as well as `beans.xml`. What should I do with those classes or change or add, in order to run my service on the server (.war web-apps on TomEE deploy automatically)?

P.S. and I'm not allowed to use Spring

Comment: what does your tomee startup log say? is the endpoint registered? do you have a tomee.xml in your conf folder?

Comment: @Kekzpanda sorry for not answering, the problem was that TomEE doesn'T support Java 11 features, so I downgrade my code to Java 8 and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question: the problem was that TomEE didn't support some features from Java 11. I had to downgrade my code to Java 8 and it worked after.